# Google firestore to get single record. but not able to cast to object

Tags: javascript, angular, google-cloud-firestore

This is my controller class. where i want to convert data to my custom object

```ts
getRegister(node:string) {
   
    this.db.firestore.collection('databasetable')
        .where('profileId','==', node)
        .get()
        .then(querySnapshot => {
                querySnapshot.forEach(function (doc) {
                      console.log(doc.id); // id of doc
                      console.log(doc.data()); // data of doc
                      //Want to cast my object here for displaying into UI
                })
         });
         
  }
```

Comment: Your code should be `querySnapshot.docs.forEach`

Answer (score 1):

The `data()` method always returns a JSON object. I think you're looking for the (relatively recent) `withConverter` methods and `FirestoreDataConverter` class:

```
await firebase.firestore()
  .collection('posts')
  .withConverter(postConverter) //  this is a custom class that performs the conversion
  .doc().get();
```

The `postConverter` above is an object that has `toFirestore` and `fromFirestore` methods to convert the JSON from/to the custom class, for example:

```
const postConverter = {
  toFirestore(post: Post): firebase.firestore.DocumentData {
    return {title: post.title, author: post.author};
  },
  fromFirestore(
    snapshot: firebase.firestore.QueryDocumentSnapshot,
    options: firebase.firestore.SnapshotOptions
  ): Post {
    const data = snapshot.data(options)!;
    return new Post(data.title, data.author);
  }
};
```

Also see the documentation for the [`DocumentReference.withConverter` method](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference#withconverter) and the [`FirestoreDataConverter` class](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.FirestoreDataConverter), where I got the above code samples from.